# Swagger Obsolete Message

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

When i add an Obsolete attribute to a controller action swagger correctly shows the endpoint as Deprecated in the UI but it dosn't show the Message. For example.

```
[Obsolete("This endpoint will no longer be supported. Use /api/somepath instead")]
```

Is it possible to see this message in swagger ui?

**Edit**

We are using Swashbuckle for integration with ASP.net Web Api

Comment: Which framework do you use? Swashbuckle?

Comment: Ah sorry i didn't realize there were different frameworks, but yes it looks like we are using Swashbuckle.

Comment: Try with Swagger-Net, I've been working on that and I just added this feature.